# Mysql Schema in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am developing a web service with Node.js,but I will work with mysql, I used to use mongoDB and I could create an Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/webservice', function(err) {
  if (err) {
      throw err;
  } else {
      console.log('Connected');
  }
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   email: String,
   city: String,
   age: String
 });


var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

But with Mysql? I have the next code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password:''
});

connection.connect(function(err){
   if(err){
      console.log(err);
   }
  console.log("Connected...");  
 });
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Well you can't use Mongoose to create a MySQl Schema if that's what you're asking. You'll need some other library.

Comment: yeah the modules are different, but with module mysql there any way to create a Schema ?

Comment: Check out http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike mongoDB where Collections are created if they don't exist, you have to manually create tables in MySQL. You can create a table for your users with the following query:

`CREATE TABLE NOT EXISTS Users (id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(30),email VARCHAR(255),city VARCHAR(50),age INT);`

```
connection.query('CREATE TABLE NOT EXISTS Users (id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(30),email VARCHAR(255),city VARCHAR(50),age INT);', function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Users TABLE created.');
});
```